# How do you get the td values in each iteration of tr?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, autotest

This is the table below that I need to iterate.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Thomas Hill</td>
        <td>4</td
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Greg Hill</td>
        <td>39</td
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Jane Hill</td>
        <td>31</td
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying get the first td each and code it like this.

```
let values = []
cy.get('tbody > tr')
  .find('td')
  .each(($el, $index) => {
     cy.wrap($el)
      .invoke('text')
      .then(num => {
          if($index!==0)
            values.push(num)
          })
       })
```

Upon searching it, the arrays has no value. I want to get value of the first TD only in each row.

Comment: can you try `cy.log($el.text())` inside `each()` and tell me whats the output.

Comment: It gets one row only.

Comment: Can you change the locator to `cy.get('tbody > tr > td')` and remove `find()`. and then use `cy.log($el.text())` and let me know what do you get. remove everything else from each.

Comment: all the rows and its tds

Comment: So you get something like 1 2 3. Is this want you in the array ?

Comment: Yes only that except the name and the number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223342/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-william).

Answer (score 0):

You say that you try to invoke the first Td value, of each row, but you are invoking a command that gets each Td in the code. Here is my suggestion

```
let values = []
cy.get('tbody > tr')
    .each(($el) => {
        cy.wrap($el)
            .find('td')
            .first()
            .invoke('text')
            .then(num => {
                values.push(num)
            })
    })
```